# onClick notification flutter not working , even when app is in foreground

Tags: firebase, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-local-notification

I am trying to redirect the page to the `DummyScreen` here..as soon as the notification is clicked.
But my methods are not working, Even when the app is in foreground resume or background , it isn't working in either cases.

- I want to redirect all the notifications irrespective of the app state to the `DummyScreen`
- I am looking for redirecting of the onClick of the notification in all the possible scenarios of the app

  - Forground
  - background
  - onResume

So far my code ..

```
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  print('Handling a background message ${message.messageId}');
  print("The message is $message");
}

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp().then((value) => Get.put(OrderController()));
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);

  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  late AndroidNotificationChannel channel;
  var logger = Logger();

  
  late FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loadFCM(context);
    listenFCM();
  }

  void loadFCM(BuildContext context) async {
    if (!kIsWeb) {
      channel = const AndroidNotificationChannel(
        'high_importance_channel', // id
        'High Importance Notifications', // title
        importance: Importance.high,
        enableVibration: true,
      );

      flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

      var details = await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.getNotificationAppLaunchDetails();
      if (details!.didNotificationLaunchApp) {
        print(details.payload);
      }

      await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
          .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
          ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);
      const AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid = AndroidInitializationSettings('app_icon');
      final InitializationSettings initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
        android: initializationSettingsAndroid,
      );
      await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings, onSelectNotification: (String? payload) {
        print("I am the payload." + (payload ?? ""));
        Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => DummyScreen()));
      });
      await FirebaseMessaging.instance.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
        alert: true,
        badge: true,
        sound: true,
      );
    }
  }
 void listenFCM() async {
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;
      AndroidNotification? android = message.notification?.android;
      if (notification != null && android != null && !kIsWeb) {
        flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
          notification.hashCode,
          notification.title,
          notification.body,
          NotificationDetails(
            android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
              channel.id,
              channel.name,
              // TODO add a proper drawable resource to android, for now using
              //      one that already exists in example app.
              icon: 'launch_background',
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    });
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      routes: {
        'details-screen': (context) => const DetailsScreen(),
      },
      theme: ThemeData(
         primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}
```

And i am sending notification using the following method. From another app

```
void sendPushMessage(String name, double totalPrice) async {
  try {
    await http.post(
      Uri.parse('https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send'),
      headers: <String, String>{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'key=$AuthorizationToken',
      },
      body: jsonEncode(
        <String, dynamic>{
          'notification': <String, dynamic>{
            'body': '$name ordered items worth \u{20B9}$totalPrice',
            'title': 'Hey! There\'s a new order'
          },
          'priority': 'high',
          'data': <String, dynamic>{
            'click_action': 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK',
            'id': '1',
            'status': 'done'
          },
          "to": AdminToken,
        },
      ),
    );
  } catch (e) {
    print("error push notification");
  }
}
```